# ModSecurity subrequest whitelist

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, mod-security2

I have Nginx with ModSecurity and the OWASP CRS setup being used as a reverse proxy to a couple different web servers. I am using `add_after_body /gdprmessage.html;` to append a GDPR acceptance to every page. Everything works fairly well, but occasionally on POST requests, the resulting page will render an ugly 403 error rather than my GDPR message. I get this message in the logs:

```
2020/07/24 22:42:42 [error] 19576#0: *1664601 [client 10.0.0.10] ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Matched "Operator `Ge' with parameter `5' against variable `TX:ANOMALY_SCORE' (Value: `5' ) [file "/etc/nginx/owasp-modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-949-BLOCKING-EVALUATION.conf"] [line "80"] [id "949110"] [rev ""] [msg "Inbound Anomaly Score Exceeded (Total Score: 5)"] [data ""] [severity "2"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.2.0"] [maturity "0"] [accuracy "0"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-generic"] [hostname "10.0.0.2"] [uri "/wp-login.php"] [unique_id "159562336247.351441"] [ref ""], client: 10.0.0.10, server: test.com, request: "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1", subrequest: "/gdprmessage.html", host: "www.test.com", referrer: "https://www.test.com/wp-login.php"
```

The login page content renders fine, but the GDPR subrequest does not. I tried to fix this by adding the following to my ModSec rules:

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI "/gdprmessage.html" "id:33000,phase:1,nolog,allow,ctl:ruleRemoveById=949110"
```

This did not work, so I tried this to whitelist the request entirely with:

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI "/gdprmessage.html" "id:33000,phase:1,log,allow,ctl:ruleEngine=Off"
```

This also did not work. I reasoned that the `REQUEST_URI` possibly only had the original request, so I tested:

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI "/wp-login.php" "id:33000,phase:1,log,allow,ctl:ruleEngine=Off"
```

This "worked", but is not a solution. I looked through all of the Variables on https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-%28v2.x%29#Variables available to `SecRule`, but did not see anything that would provide the "subrequest" value.

Is there a way that I can whitelist my `/gdprmessage.html` subrequest, leaving the CRS in for the requests themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to solve the issue with a ModSecurity exception. It turns out, the answer was simply adding `modsecurity off` to the location.

If it helps anyone else, here is my GDPR snippet that include in my site definitions:

```
add_after_body /gdprmessage.html;

location = /gdprmessage.html {
    root /etc/nginx/snippets/;
    modsecurity off;

    if ($http_x_requested_with = XMLHttpRequest) {
        return 200;
    }
}
```

Testing for XMLHttpRequests ensures my GDPR message is not appended to ajax queries.